# Issue with new version of application for BlackBerry App World

Tags: blackberry, release, blackberry-world

What would be the process for BlackBerry App World to submit new release of existing application and make it available on a specific date? This is a 'free' application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specify an app to be released on a specific date, regardless of whether it's a new app or a new version of an existing app.

With new apps your app will be reviewed and approved by RIM but not posted for sale until you click the 'release for sale' button. For new versions of existing apps your updated app is placed for sale as soon as it's approved. You will receive email notification when this happens.

As a rough guide here's how long it takes for apps to reviewed and published:

- New apps: 1-2 weeks
- New versions of existing apps: 24-48 hours

Comment: My understanding that when I submit new application I have an option to control release date. First it gets reviewed/approved by RIM then I can click 'release for sale'. But in case of new version for an existing application it gets released for public automatically after RIM's approval. Am I correct about new application flow?

Answer (score -1):

you have to Relese new version in app world. click on `plus sign` to relese new version and follw the instriction.
Once when u submit for `Release` it will automatically `Approved` by `RIM` after few days. we cant `Release` is on specific 
day . But yes When our App is `ready for sale` you cant do the your app hide . when u once click `release for sale` than it will see on app world.

Comment: After uploading new version it goes to 'draft' mode and you have only 'Submit releases for Approval'. Then after RIM approval it becomes 'live' unless I'm missing something.

Comment: when it is Approved by RIM it will be live with new version. But you can hide it using "Remove from sale" than it will not display in app world

Comment: Consider removing your `Code` markup and unnecessary capitalization - it makes your answer difficult to read.

Comment: If I use 'remove from sale' I think will it remove the whole application not just new version of the application. Can somebody confirm it?

Comment: yes @AlexMSU if u "remove from sale" than your hole app will be removed from the app world. You cant see it in app world